# AttributeError: type object 'fft' has no attribute 'fft_vcc'

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I tried the flow graph shown below, but I get the following error and cannot run it.
What could be the cause? Thanks.

```
Executing: /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/nomo/fft.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nomo/fft.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/nomo/fft.py", line 208, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/home/nomo/fft.py", line 159, in __init__
    self.fft_vxx_0 = fft.fft_vcc(fftsize, True, window.blackmanharris(1024), True, 1)
AttributeError: type object 'fft' has no attribute 'fft_vcc'
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to C++ at all, so I removed the tag. Please don't tag unrelated languages.

Comment: We have no idea what your code is, so there's no way we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a name conflict: You try to use the `fft` module (as imported in your python by `from gnuradio import fft`, but you also have declared the ID of this flowgraph class to be `fft`. So, Python picks the wrong one.

Pick any other `Id` in your `Options` block and the error will go away.

Comment: It was resolved. Thank you very much.